# ember trigger action from console

Tags: javascript, ember.js, console, action

```
App = Ember.Application.create();

posts = [{
  title: "Rails is omakase",
  body: "There are lots of à la carte software environments in this world."
}, {
  title: "Broken Promises",
  body: "James Coglan wrote a lengthy article about Promises in node.js."
}];

App.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    return posts; 
  }
});

App.PostSummaryComponent = Ember.Component.extend({
  actions: {
    toggleBody: function() {
      this.toggleProperty('isShowingBody');
    }
  }
});
```

What do I suppose to do if I want to call toggleBody function from my browser console.
The above code is presented in ember.js document, http://emberjs.com/guides/components/handling-user-interaction-with-actions/

Answer (score 1):

This is a really old thread, but from devtools you can do:

```
App.__container__.lookup('component:post-summary').send('toggleBody');
```